# Does the length of a table name affect performance?

Tags: postgresql, naming-convention

PostgreSQL table names are limited to 63 chars.

Is there a performance gain to be had if I limit my table names to something like 5 chars or can I use the full 63 chars without consequence?

I understand it will be longer to type long names when creating queries, but that's what aliases are for.

Comment: No, I doubt there is difference in performance. No reason to limit to 5 characters and seriously, will you ever need 63 characters for a name?

Comment: @hypercube : well right now in my conceptual model I have a 20+ char name, something like 'customer_pays_for_user'. I was wondering if I should start to shorten the long names or just go with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Table names have to be stored just like any other data (in the system catalog [`pg_class`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-class.html) to be precise), and there are multiple objects that are typically named matching the table name (constraints, indexes, sequences, ...) so there is a marginal cost for longer strings. But you will not be able to notice any difference in performance. Internal references are implemented with [oid numbers (object identifier types)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html), so independent of the string used as name.

The more important consideration is that your code becomes longer and harder to read and type. Typos more likely. Aliases are nice, but you still have to spell out the name in many places. So the rule of thumb should be:

- As short as possible.
- As long as necessary to be clear.

Comment: 'But you will not be able to notice any difference in performance.' does this hold true if I have several thousand users accessing the database ?

Comment: @jmn: Yes. The performance penalty is just too marginal.